# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am getting an exception while trying delete query :

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! 
On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters
```

My query is like :

```
@Query(value = "delete from my_table where col1 = :col1_param and col2 = :col2_param", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
int deleteByCol1AndCol2(@Param("col1_param") String col1, @Param("col2_param") String col2);
```

As you can see I use @Param spring-data annotation.

In fact while testing locally I dont get the error, but after deploy on server I get the error.
Both local and server environnement use java 7 version, but slightly different :

Local :

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Server (qualification) :

```
$JAVA_HOME/java -version 
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6470sr10fp90-20210714_01(SR10 FP90))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20210623_007887 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR10_20210623_1455_B7887
JIT  - r11_20210623_7887
GC   - R26_Java726_SR10_20210623_1455_B7887_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20210623_7887)
JCL - 20210623_01 based on Oracle jdk7u311-b07
```

Comment: Would it work if you used jdbc?

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy I realy dont use JDBC but JPA instead !

Comment: That's good, but could you please still try it?